# Post in jquery do not work

Tags: jquery

When I use post in jQuery, it is not working. I do not know why. I know that simple code for that. I will appreciate any help.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var ae = $('#form').serialize();
        $.post('post.php',ae,function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: change it to `.post` not `.get`.

Comment: yeah but i tried with post but still not working

Comment: Define "not working".  Does the code execute at all?  Are there any errors on the browser's debugging console?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Use your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: when i  use  get it is work without any problems but when i replace get to post and change method to post and change in php $_GET to $_POST but not working  and i use  google chrome.

Comment: @alshbah: So maybe the problem is in the server-side code?  Unless you can define the nature of the problem, there isn't much anybody here can do but wildly guess.  You have debugging tools available to you, you need to use them.

Comment: Maybe there is problem with the server side code . anyway thank you ^_^'

Comment: add some error handling!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the .get instead of .post.
This will result in an http get instead of an http post.

Comment: yeah you are right but why post is still not working ??